# modal pop up extender

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I'm doing is creating a list of tickets using a ListView. One of the controls in the item template is a link button that shows the header of the ticket. When the user clicks the link button, I want to open a modal window that shows the ticket in readable format. To get the ticket, I'll be passing that page a variable and it'll do the rest; nothing complicated. The page will have 3 buttons and the windows needs to close when you click one of them.

Now, I figured out how to use the ModalPopupExtender from the Ajax tookit more or less. You create the panel in it's own div which stays hidden. I created a click event that basically uses a webclient to download the html from the page and insert it into that div's innerHtml. This seems to work the first time. But as soon as you click a different link, the page pukes and says something about it being in an illegal state.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this wrong, and I can't find any decent examples of how to do this. Well there's one, but the english is hard to understand and it's in VB instead of C#. Any help?

Comment: Code says more than 1000 words. Show us some aspx markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>  
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><asp:toolkitscriptmanager id="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">          </asp:toolkitscriptmanager>
        <br />
        <asp:modalpopupextender dropshadow="true" okcontrolid="btnOk" cancelcontrolid="btnClose" runat="server" popupcontrolid="Panel1" id="ModalPopupExtender1" targetcontrolid="Button1" />
        <asp:panel id="Panel1" runat="server" cssclass="modalPopup" style="display: none;">  This is basic modal popup.  <br /><br />  
            <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" />  <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close Me" />    
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>   
        </asp:panel>
        <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="First Modal Popup" />
    </div>
</form>
```